# GitHubソースコードのライセンスについて

Tags: github, ライセンス

ポートフォリオのソースコードをGithubで公開しています。

ポートフォリオであるため、READMEに改変や再配布の禁止を明示しておきたいのですが、
調べてもそのようなライセンス表記を見つけられなかったため質問した次第です。

最低限、プライベートな利用の範囲に制限しておきたいと思っています。

表記しても改変や再配布されるリスクは当然ありますが、それは非公開にするしかないと思うので、
あくまで公開している上で利用の制限を明示するライセンス表記を知りたく思います。

そもそもGitHubのリポジトリを公開している時点でそのように明示することがGithub的に禁止されているのであれば教えて下さい。

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: [利用規約上forkを禁止することはできない](https://docs.github.com/ja/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/licensing-a-repository)ことは分かりましたが、その上で改変を禁止することが不可能であるかは分かりませんでした。

Comment: 「ポートフォリオであるため」は、どの部分に掛かってきますか？ / 著作権は一般的に「創作物」に対しての話だと思うので、今回の例であればポートフォリオ(ページ)のデザインであれば著作権の主張も問題ないでしょう。 / 一方で、個人のプロフィールや経歴のような情報は著作権の対象になるのかな？と少し疑問に思いました。 (自分も詳しいわけではないので、的はずれなことを書いているかもしれません)

Comment: 目的は違いますが、Unityのソースコードなんかは意味合いが近いんじゃないでしょうか。 https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference   https://jp.gamesindustry.biz/article/1803/18032703/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

研究用ライセンスなどで商用利用禁止など用途を限定している例はあります。
https://github.com/search?l=Text&q=non-commercial+purpose&type=Code

GitHubによるライセンス解説サイトでは、ライセンス指定無しの場合にそういったGitHub上でのフォークと表示以外は合法的にコピー、配布、変更ができない可能性があるとしています。つまり非推奨ながら禁止されてもいないようです。
https://choosealicense.com/no-permission/